# resilience4j circuit breaker on multiple cloud instances

Tags: cloud, multiple-instances, resilience4j

I have a usecase where I am running **multiple instances** of a single spring boot application on PCF

Now I have introduced circuit breaker annotation for one of the call.

#### Problem

When calls are failing across instances, resilience4j is **counting failures on instance level** instead of service level (which is 1) and opening circuit accordingly for individual instance.

#### Questions to clarify

1. Is it expected behavior?
2. Is there a way (property) to have these counter on service level?

Answer (score 1):

1.) Yes that's the expected behavior. 2.) No